# OOP mapping two tables-- two objects? Or one object that knows more than it should?

Tags: php, oop, aggregation

I have two tables, A and B. Most of my data comes from table A, but I also need to verify that some information (address and email) is the same as what is in table B.  I can access that information with the query,

`select a.address, a.email, b.address, b.email from a, left join b on a.uniqueAttr=b.uniqueAttr`

I'm trying to do things the OOP way, but I've been struggling to figure out where this fits in the grand scheme, because object A really shouldn't care about information in table B.

My first idea is to do something like this pseudocode:

```
<?php
// list view
$a = new aList;
$rows = $a->findAll();
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($rows); $i++) {
    $b = new bList;
    $foreignRow = $b->find($row->foreignKey);

    // do something with the info
    if($foreignRow->address != $a->address) { $error = 'address'; }

    // do template stuff...
}
```

But if I do it this way,

1. I'm going to have to make a new query in b each time I iterate through the list generated by a.  That's not very efficient, especially if the list gets long (although I plan to implement pagination).
2. It still reeks of procedural programming, because I should be able to check `$someObject->isAddressSame()`

The other option that I see is to

1. Add a method to objectA, that left joins table B (in case there is no matching record) and returns a list including table B's attributes.
2. Implement another method that checks if the addresses are the same.

Pseudocode:

```
<?php
// list view
$a = new aList;
$rows = $a->findAllWithTableB();
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($rows); $i++) {
  $error = $a->isAddressSame($row);
  // do other view stuff
}
```

But this seems like it's repeating the `->findAll()` method) and it has objectA knowing things about table B that it probably shouldn't know.

Am I being too paranoid about how much objectA knows?

Comment: Your domain object should not be responsible for storing itself: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

Comment: I'm not well-versed on domain objects.  Are you saying that the database access should be abstracted out of the business logic, or am I missing your point completely?

Comment: Can't edit my comment... Didn't see your link.  Thanks.